# Read object from an AsyncTask

Tags: java

Iam doing a SocketProgramming on Android Studio and I want to read an Object from inside a AsyncTask block on ClientSide. How should I do it?

```
private class CLientBlock extends AsyncTask<ServerSocket, myObjectName, Void>{
protected Void doInBackground(ServerSocket... sockets) {
....
ObjectInputStream ois =new ObjectInputStream(new  <????>);
...
...}
}
```

What should be the signature of the AsyncTAsk block to accept the Object?
How should I use the ObjectinputStream?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what would you like to do with the object that you read, if you're going to process it  then you do that inside the doInBackground method and just pass to the asynctask the ServerSocket. To read the object just get the InputStream from the ServerSocket and use the readObject methodand cast it to the object you want. You can even check that the object is an instance of the class you want using instanceof.